# What is superradiance?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics, terminology, coherence, pulsars

What is [superradiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superradiance)? I came across this term recently (used widely to explain fast radio bursts). After googling a bit, what I understand is:
When several atoms are confined in a very small area and one of the atoms emits a photon (spontaneously and randomly), it affects all other excited atoms in its neighborhood to release their excess energy at the same moment producing an intense flash of light. The small area confinement is such that the area is smaller than the wavelength of the photons.

Can someone illustrate a bit more on this topic?

Edit 1: In pulsars or FRBs, this is also called antenna emission/ spatial bunching. Researchers working on pulsars might be having a good knowledge of this phenomenon. The other type of coherent radio emission is synchrotron maser emission.

Answer (score -1):

The boundaries aren't hard and fast, but here's the basic heirarchy.

1. fluorescence:  photons emitted as electrons randomly drop to a lower state
2. superfluorescence:  photons emitted with a "little bit" of stimulated emission but the overall emission pulse doesn't show measurable coherence.
3. superradiance: as you wrote, localized bursts of stimulated coherent emission
4. lasing:  overwhelming majority of photon emission is due to stimulated, in-phase emission.